# How do I join two column values in string with empty values and integer in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So, I have the following data frame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [4444,1111,np.nan, np.nan], "col2":["ABC", "BCD", "DEF", "FGH"]})
df
```

I want to combine the values from those two columns into one separated by an underscore. I don't want to have underscores in column with nan values. So far I have tried this.

```
df['col3'] = df['col2']+"_"+df['col1'].fillna("").astype(str)
df
```

But the result is unsatisfying.

[image]

I don't want the trailing underscore for column without number. And I don't want to have that 0, but I failed to convert them to integer without running into an error.

My expected result is like this.

```
["ABC_4444", "BCD_1111", "DEF", "FGH"]
```

I believe this should be pretty simple, but I am stuck. It's probably important to mention that this code is part of a longer function. So I pretty much prefer a lighter computation and shorter code as to not make the function look even more complicated than it already is. How do I approach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other way via `np.where()`

check for NaN's in column 'col1' and If found then put the values of 'col2' else put 'col1','col2' joined with '_':

```
df['col3']=np.where(
                  df['col1'].isna(),
                  df['col2'],
                  df['col2']+'_'+df['col1'].astype(str).str.strip('.0')
                   )
```

Output of `df`:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   4444.0  ABC     ABC_4444
1   1111.0  BCD     BCD_1111
2   NaN     DEF     DEF
3   NaN     FGH     FGH
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [4444,1111,np.nan, np.nan], "col2":["ABC", "BCD", "DEF", "FGH"]})
df['col3'] = 'nan'
ind = df['col1'].isnull()
df['col3'][~ind] = df['col2'][~ind]+"_"+df['col1'][~ind].astype(int).astype(str)
df['col3'][ind] = df['col2'][ind]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select` and apply the string concatenation only on the rows that doesn't have `NaN` for `col1`, you also need to replace anything from the decimal point since you are directly converting float type column to string:

```py
>>> df['col3']=np.select([df['col1'].notna()],
                    [df['col2'] + "_" + df['col1'].astype(str).replace('(\.\d+)', '', regex=True)],
                    df['col2']
                    )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     col1 col2      col3
0  4444.0  ABC  ABC_4444
1  1111.0  BCD  BCD_1111
2     NaN  DEF       DEF
3     NaN  FGH       FGH
```